# Detecting if an arc has been clicked in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am currently trying to digitalize an boardgame I invented (repo: https://github.com/zutn/King_of_the_Hill). To make it work I need to check if one of the tiles (the arcs) on this [board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTXzF.jpg) have been clicked. So far I have not been able to figure a way without giving up the pygame.arc function for drawing. If I use the x,y position of the position clicked, I can't figure a way out to determine the exact outline of the arc to compare to. I thought about using a color check, but this would only tell me if any of the tiles have been clicked. So is there a convenient way to test if an arc has been clicked in pygame or do I have to use sprites or something completely different? Additionally in a later step units will be included, that are located on the tiles. This would make the solution with the angle calculation postet below much more diffcult.

Comment: What if did like this: take the center point as a the origo in a 2 dimensional coordinate system. Calculated the angle between the mouse click and the origin to determine which set of tiles which were click. Then calculate the distance between the mouse click and the origin to determine which tile was clicked.

Comment: That could be working. Thanks a lot. I will try it out and report back. Additional ideas still welcome though.

Comment: I'm sorry I had forgot to add that there will be units on the tiles as well, making this way impossible (at least as I imagine it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple arc class that will detect if a point is contained in the arc, but it will only work with circular arcs.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
from math import atan2, pi

class CircularArc:

    def __init__(self, color, center, radius, start_angle, stop_angle, width=1):
        self.color = color
        self.x = center[0]  # center x position
        self.y = center[1]  # center y position
        self.rect = [self.x - radius, self.y - radius, radius*2,  radius*2]
        self.radius = radius
        self.start_angle = start_angle
        self.stop_angle = stop_angle
        self.width = width




    def draw(self, canvas):
        pygame.draw.arc(canvas, self.color, self.rect, self.start_angle, self.stop_angle, self.width)



    def contains(self, x, y):

        dx = x - self.x   # x distance
        dy = y - self.y   # y distance

        greater_than_outside_radius = dx*dx + dy*dy >= self.radius*self.radius

        less_than_inside_radius = dx*dx + dy*dy <= (self.radius- self.width)*(self.radius- self.width)

        # Quickly check if the distance is within the right range
        if greater_than_outside_radius or less_than_inside_radius:
            return False



        rads = atan2(-dy, dx)  # Grab the angle

        # convert the angle to match up with pygame format. Negative angles don't work with pygame.draw.arc
        if rads < 0:
            rads = 2 * pi + rads


        # Check if the angle is within the arc start and stop angles
        return self.start_angle <= rads <= self.stop_angle
```

Here's some example usage of the class. Using it requires a center point and radius instead of a rectangle for creating the arc.

```
pygame.init()


black = ( 0, 0, 0)
width = 800
height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


distance = 100
tile_num = 4
ring_width = 20

arc = CircularArc((255, 255, 255), [width/2, height/2], 100, tile_num*(2*pi/7), (tile_num*(2*pi/7))+2*pi/7, int(ring_width*0.5))

while True:

    fill_color = black

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # quit if the quit button was pressed
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


    # Change color when the mouse touches
    if arc.contains(x, y):
        fill_color = (200, 0, 0)


    screen.fill(fill_color)
    arc.draw(screen)
    # screen.blit(debug, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.